# Where to configure synaptics touchpad to use inverted two finger scrolling?

Tags: synaptics

I want to configure my synaptics touchpad to user inverted scrolling with two fingers.

Where to configure synaptics for this in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: @dobey maybe the grammar. I have to edit the question.

Comment: "Inverted" scrolling? So you want the wheel to scroll up when you move fingers down?

Comment: There is a [very similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/203018/107321), with more answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is relatively straightforward to do this, but it may not work for all touchpads, although it worked for my Synaptics Touchpad on my old laptop. I began experimenting with mine and using `xinput`, etc, and did mostly the same as [this useful article here](http://www.andybarratt.co.uk/lion-like-scrolling-on-ubuntu-inverse-scrolling-on-linux).

Firstly, run `xinput` to list all your devices, and note the id of your touchpad.

```
↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Now to get your button map for the device number found:

```
xinput get-button-map 11
```

which should return something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Now, just reversing 4 and 5 should invert the 2 finger scrolling (at least it does on **my** system). In the following command, just remember to use your device hardware id (not my example `11`) and leave spaces between the numbers *after* the device number:

```
xinput set-button-map 11 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Now with `xinput get-button-map 11` the button map should be

```
1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Now, check it in your web browser. This of course only sets it **temporarily**, so it is probably easiest to add it as a startup item rather than messing with `xorg`. Just create a new startup item and add the whole of the above `xinput set-button-map` command in it. It is critical that there are spaces between the numbers after your device number, and of course use the actual device name of your hardware, not my example.

Again, see [the article](http://www.andybarratt.co.uk/lion-like-scrolling-on-ubuntu-inverse-scrolling-on-linux) and [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664418) for more information and discussion- you can probably experiment and invert a lot of the other functions of the touchpad as well; you can reset your experimentation (which is temporary anyway, unless you put a command in startup) by just simply placing the numbers in order again:

```
xinput set-button-map 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Personally I use `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12"` but this seems to work as well :)

Answer (score 2):

The Arch Linux Wiki has a good tutorial at:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Synaptics_Touchpad#Configuration

The only major requirement is an understanding of how to edit configuration files.

The main point to focus on at this URL is setting VertScrollDelta (and HorizScrollDelta if you enabled horizontal scrolling) to a negative value. What I do is take the previous value of this variable and set it to itself with a minus sign in front of it (e.g. instead of 106, use -106).

If Linux isn't your expertise, I'd suggest you read the entire article to gain a basic understanding of what to do.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the best way to do this is by using dconf-editor:

- Open Terminal
- Type in *deconf-editor* and hit Enter
- Now go to **org>gnome>settings-daemon>peripherals>touchpad** and now you can make most of the changes you want

Here's a screenshot of deconf-editor:

[image: deconf-editor]

Answer (score 0):

For inverted scrolling, open gedit (or your favourite text editor) and type this:

```
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12
```

This enable vertical and horizontal natural scrolling (i.e. inverted scrolling). 4 and 5 interchanged is for inverted vertical. 6 and 7 interchanged is for inverted horizontal. Now, save this file as **.Xmodmap** in your home folder.

Next, for 2 finger scrolling, open **Mouse and Touchpad Settings** in **System Settings**, go to the **Touchpad** tab and check the box which says **Two-finger scrolling**. The screenshot below will show you this.

[image: Touchpad settings]

Answer (score 0):

For inverted scrolling, there an indicator you can install at https://launchpad.net/~zedtux/+archive/naturalscrolling.

In summary :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zedtux/naturalscrolling
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install naturalscrolling
```

Then run Natural Scrolling from your Dash. An indicator icon will appear where you can invert scrolling on a per-device basis (e.g. invert your trackapd, but don't invert your bluetooth mouse).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use reverted/inverted/natural scrolling (whatever you call it), create file containing these line, right click, properties, and make it executable, add the file to Startup Application, and reboot.

```
#!/bin/sh
DEV_NO=`xinput list | grep "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" | sed 's/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/g'`
PROP_NO=`xinput list-props ${DEV_NO} | grep "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" | sed 's/.*(\([0-9]*\)).*/\1/g'`
xinput set-prop ${DEV_NO} ${PROP_NO} -106 -106
```

direct link download https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75813759/.nat

Comment: please add # before !/bin/sh, sorry I can't do proper formatting because I'm on mobile now, I'll upload the file once I get to computer.

Comment: Have update my answer