# Two mice: change primary button of just *one* of them?

Tags: mouse

I have two mice connected to my computer, one on each side of the keyboard.

Both mice are working: they move the pointer, and both buttons work (one is a DeathAdder, one is a Sensei, if that matters).

When opening the mouse section, I would have expected to see two configurations, but I only see one. It seems to be shared, as changing "Primary Button" changes primary button for both mice.

However, I would like the left mouse to have the primary button on the right and the right mouse to have its primary button on the left.

How can I accomplish that?

[image: mouse configuration screen]

Comment: This would be a very similar answer to the one I reference in the close vote - if you are running xorg (as opposed to wayland) you can change the appropriate mouse using `xinput`

Answer (score 0):

you can't by design from the GUI! Because the configuration thinks in term of class of devices indeed any modification affect the whole mouse class.

But like pointed from Charles Green you can use `xinput`

here one possible answer with 2 mouse with different configuration:
[How can I change mouse keymapping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213712/how-can-i-change-mouse-keymapping)

Comment: This is really only true of the GUI interface - individual devices can be set through the `xinput` processes.