# trackpad script not working on startup / login

Tags: 13.04, startup, synaptics, trackpad, xps

#### The issue at hand

My aim is to enable natural scrolling on system start (or session start), which - up until now - could be easily achieved [using a startup script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203018/natural-scrolling-not-working-for-horizontal-scroll-how-to-fix-this), but since migrating from 12.04 (32 bit) to 13.04 (64 bit) I'm not able to automate this task.

Here's the script used:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
xinput set-prop 12 273 -25 -25
```

it works when running independently, so it seem to be overridden by a later call. How to resolve this?

#### What have I tried?

- Adding an entry in the Startup Applications for the trackpad script
- Using a `@reboot` flagged entry in `crontab` to call the `xinput` command
- Calling the trackpad script in `.bash_login`, or in `.profile`
- Adding a `.conf` file in `/etc/init`
- I think at some point I even tried to mess around with sequencing directories and sequencing file names under `/etc/rc*`
- Including a call in various scripts under `/etc/pm` (that actually *got things working* for the boot phase, but any subsequent suspend/sleep would deactivate the trackpad custom settings, again).

#### Environment

Dell XPS 13, Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Comment: Do you have any [finger scrolling enabled](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVoCn.png)? That *might* interfere with your script.

Comment: nop. it's not the two-finger scroll, thanks for the attempt.

Comment: Are you sure? Check *System settings* > *Mouse & Touchpad*: http://jabstaboops.andthesethygifts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/kineticscrolling1.png. There are new options in this sense in Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: yes, i am sure.

Comment: I don't want to affront you, - is this trackpad of Dell too ?! - because Logitech is supporting Linux now (they announced this one month ago). And there are trackpads of Logitech too.

Comment: @dschinn1001, i don't quite follow - how is this affronting? and if you're suggesting to try another trackpad vendor - it's not an option, as the trackpad is a built-in..

Comment: now I see. thought it would be an extern trackpad. could be too - that contacts of built-in trackpad are somehow interrupted (cable or contacts interrupted) ?!

Comment: @dschinn1001 - the trackpad *is working fine*, it's the settings that's broken.. thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't explain why it is happening, it's just a workaround.

You could automatically reset the property whenever it changes. Use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  xinput list-props 12 | grep -q "Synaptics Scrolling Distance (273):.*-25, -25" || xinput set-prop 12 273 -25 -25
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: that's great, man. i was thinking along these lines (i.e. having a sleep once to avoid override by other scripts on startup), but it seems too dirty a solution. still it's the only thing that works for now. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a Dell Inspiron 17R, and my touchpad was only recognized as a PS/2 mouse.  I found a post on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102346) that contained a custom driver to enable the touchpad features.  Once I installed it, Ubuntu's System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad settings  listed the touchpad options.  And then a post on how to enable [Natural Scrolling](http://linuxg.net/enable-horizontal-and-natural-scrolling-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/) using dconf-editor.  I hope this helps.

Comment: this is hardly related to the issue, my trackpad is working fine, and i can configure natural scrolling with no particular problem. the problem i'm having has to do with *startup scripts*, please read the question thoroughly before posting an answer.