# touchpad two finger scroll too fast

Tags: 18.04, hp

I have a HP Probook 450 g1. I want to change the touchpad two finger scroll speed. I tried some package but nothing seems to work. also the touchpad seems to be more sensitive. is there any way to control that?

A package with UI would be a big help.

Comment: Have you tried  to go to: Settings - Devices - Mouse & Touchpad, then adjust Touchpad - Touchpad speed?

Comment: touchpad speed changes my pointer speed. but the two finger scrolling speed remains same.

Answer (score 4):

The default `libinput` touchpad driver installed in recent versions of Ubuntu does not have an option to adjust the two-finger scrolling speed. You can see that from the output of `xinput --list-props <id>` where `<id>` is the device ID of your touchpad as obtained from `xinput list`.

However, with the HP Probook 450 G1 you are lucky as a Google search seems to indicate that it has a Synaptics touchpad. For this, an alternative driver is available with more options.

1. Install the Synaptics driver as follows and it should already work ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035863)):

   ```
   sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
   ```
2. If it does not work yet, also follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103903) to override the `libinput` touchpad driver explicitly.
3. Configure the option `Synaptics Scrolling Distance` with a command like the one below. `<id>` is the device ID of your touchpad as obtained from `xinput list`, and you have to play with the values for the vertical and horizontal scrolling distance at the end of the line to find the right ones for you. If you use negative values it will give you inverted / natural scrolling.

   ```
   xinput --set-prop <id> 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' 8 8
   ```
4. Once you found the right values, make them permanent using [a solution from here](https://askubuntu.com/q/203018).

Comment: So helpful, thanks! I found my pointer too slow, and my two-finger scroll too fast under Ubuntu 18.04 my C720 chromebook. Using this info, I found the following settings worked perfect (my device ID was 12): `xinput --set-prop <id> 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' 26 26` and `xinput --set-prop <id> 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration' 1.4` -- and storing these lines in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc` makes them permanent. Thanks again!

Comment: And bonus -- I could increase the sensitivity (how softly I can press to engage actions) by turning down the numbers listed under "Synaptics Finger", e.g. `xinput --set-prop 12 'Synaptics Finger' 14 20 0` -- now it feels fabulously responsive (though I may still need to tune sensitivity and palm rejection -- it's a delicate balance!)

Answer (score 4):

If youre using libinput you can make the "steps" of the scrolling smaller therefore making the scroll overall slower with:

`xinput --set-prop "YOUR TOUCHPAD" "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" YOUR_SPEED`

Add `Option "ScrollPixelDistance" "YOUR_SPEED"` to your xorg conf of the Trackpad to make it permanent.

Heres the docs for some more info:

https://man.archlinux.org/man/libinput.4#SCROLL_PIXEL_DISTANCE

Comment: This needs much clarification to be a complete answer. It is currently barely any more than a link. Nothing in the question suggests that the user should know whether they use `libinput`. Nor is it clear which of the terms in the code are to be modified and which are entered verbatim. Answers should be accessible to non-power users.

Comment: this did not work. Setting it to 50 is the same as setting it to 10.