# Scrolling on touchpad too fast, property 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' doesn't exist

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, wacom, scrolling, mouse-scroll

The scrolling of my touchpad is too fast, and I tried using this solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132826/1664901) (as there is no setting for changing the scrollspeed, for some reason)

I've installed the Synapsis driver using this command:
`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
and then used `xinput list` to list the devices. It looks like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04 Mouse id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3075-002                      id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser                 id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ L U F T H Ü L S E N (AVRCP)               id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My Touchpad is the ID 9, I'm pretty sure.
Then I tried to configure the scrolling setting using this command:
`xinput --set-prop 9 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' 8 8`
It returned the following errror:
`property 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`
even tho this property should exist!
I then tried something else, another user suggested:
`xinput --set-prop 9 "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 10`
and that returned nothing, and did nothing.
When I tried inputting:
`xinput --set-prop 9 "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 1`
it returned the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x153
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

I then tried writing changes to `/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc` which also did not work.

Ubuntu Version: 22.04.1 LTS

I'm using Ubuntu on Xorg

Laptop: Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 12

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is using `libinput`, not `synaptics`. And the `9` id is your mouse. You can check what properies are there by `xinput list-props 9`

Comment: I tried changing "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" to something lower, but everything is the same (way too fast). How do I fix this?

Comment: I also tried changing it to something higher, but that had no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've figured out how to do this.
you just go into the terminal and do this:
`synclient VertScrollDelta=-100`
and that makes it a lot better.

To make the movement act like a rusty fidget spinner, you change:
`synclient CoastingFriction=35`
(The lower, the more oiled)

But doing that messes up the native settings for the touchpad, and it is now way too fast. You can fix this by doing *this* to the terminal:
`synclient MinSpeed=0.05`
followed by:
`synclient MaxSpeed=0.7`
make sure to play around with the values to your liking!

Edit: I've realised that all the settings get reset once the computer is restarted.

Comment: "all the settings get reset once the computer is restarted" — I bet there is a file somewhere where these parameters could be persisted. I might even try to use `grep -r` to find which file(s) could be identified as candidates...

Comment: Did you find the location of the file?  @Levente

Comment: No sorry, I did not attempt. I meant it as suggesting you try it.