# I have too fast two finger on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: thinkpad, scrolling, xinput, gestures

I have very fast 2-finger scroll on Thinkpad Carbon X1 Gen 6. The solutions I found on the Internet do not help me, I can't even determine which "xinput id" my touchpad has.

[image: 1]

Comment: Which applications are impacted (especially)?

Comment: I don't think wayland supports any of this. Try to use Xsession instead. (Log out, select the little cog on the right side and choose the XSession)

Comment: I tried to switch to xorg but got bad smoothness. After doing "xinput list" I got clear device names and among them was my touchpad "synaptics tm3289-021" and it had properties like "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" available. After changing this value to 8 8 (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120045/touchpad-two-finger-scroll-too-fast) I did not feel a change in the scroll speed, and I went back to wayland. Thanks for the reply, but it looks like I'll just have to get used to the responsive scrolling